# Trick MySQL into thinking that table was created with DATA DIRECTORY option

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-8.0

We are runing MySQL 5.7 that has a very large table. We want to move that table outside of data directory, to another device. MySQL [supports](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-create-table-external.html) external tables but in order for it to work the table must be **created** with `DATA DIRECTORY` option. And there seems to be no way to apply this option to existing table (alter table simply [ignores it](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html)).

But what if I "trick" MySQL into thinking that my table *was* created with this option? After comparing what my table would look like with and without this option I found four differences (beside the actual location of `ibd` file):

1. `isl` file is created
2. `INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES` contains absolute path
3. `INNODB_SYS_TABLES` flag column differs (data_dir flag)
4. `INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES` flag columns differs (not sure what flag)

If I create `isl` file manually, MySQL will update `INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES` at startup and I can actually query the table without problems. However, whenever I try operations that require copying table (like alter table with ALGORITHM=COPY) I get a file not found error. Furthermore `INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES` reports 0 in `FS_BLOCK_SIZE`, `FILE_SIZE` and `ALLOCATED_SIZE` columns.

In any case, if I go all the way and modify the flags in InnoDB system tables by directly editing my `ibdata1` file (and my table's `ibd` file), I end up with a table that looks identical to the one I created with `DATA DIRECTORY` option.

Can this solution be used or I can't just change these flags? In my understanding `DATA DIRECTORY` doesn't affect table structure so theoretical all this should be fine.

**UPDATE.** To address some of the comments: the goal is to free up disk space, table size is 15Tb and we want this to be as quick as possible, obviously. Originaly I did not want to post that, because all of this has nothing to do with my question, which is **"will the described method work in the long run?"**. I am well aware of the alternatives, including lesser known like pt-online-schema-change and gh-ost. But, for this scenario, described method should save a tremendous amount of time, you just can't beat basicaly copying a file. I am also well aware of the fact that you shouldn't do something like that in production, which is why we are currently not planning to actually use this. I'm simply asking out of the curiosity because if this indeed can be used I think it would be great if MySQL supported it. In some, albeight very rare cases, it could be a life saver, and implementation seems pretty straitforward.

Comment: What is the goal?  Running out of disk space?  I/O separation?  Something else?

Comment: The reason is disk space.

Comment: Hacking is a good way to lose data. Not recommended. If this is a development machine, go ahead and try, but never do things like this on production.

Comment: Do you know of anything specific or this is a just a general suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE new LIKE real;   with DATA DIRECTORY specified
INSERT INTO new SELECT * FROM real;   -- slow, and you should not be writing to `real`.
RENAME TABLE real TO old, new TO real;
DROP TABLE old;
```

Comment: I don't see how this answers my question. I didn't ask for solutions other than the one described in my question.

Comment: Looks like a very real, simple solution to your problem. Why try to hack something else?

Comment: Because as was stated in the first sentence: it is a very large table. And this "real" solution is only viable when you have maybe a few gigabytes of data.

Comment: How large is very large?

Comment: More than 15Tb.

Comment: @chimmi - Please edit your question to include the size, and any time constraints.

Comment: @RickJames I've updated my question, hope it clears things out. Thank you.